# How to assign groups based on a maximum sum?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'keys': list('aaaabbbbccccc'), 'values': [1, 5, 6, 8, 2, 4, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5]})

   keys  values
0     a       1
1     a       5
2     a       6
3     a       8
4     b       2
5     b       4
6     b       7
7     b       7
8     c       1
9     c       1
10    c       1
11    c       1
12    c       5
```

Further, I have a variable `max_sum = 10`.

I want to assign a group to each row (i) based on the value in `keys` and (ii) the `max_sum` which should not be exceeded per group.

My expected outcome looks like this:

```
   keys  values  group
0     a       1      1
1     a       5      1
2     a       6      2
3     a       8      3
4     b       2      4
5     b       4      4
6     b       7      5
7     b       7      6
8     c       1      7
9     c       1      7
10    c       1      7
11    c       1      7
12    c       5      7
```

So, the first two values in the `a` group (`1` and `5`) sum up to `6` which is less than `10`, so they are in the same group. If we now added also `6`, `max_sum` would be exceeded and therefore this value goes into group `2`. We cannot add `8` to this group as then again `max_sum` would be exceeded, therefore we define a group `3`. Same then for the values `b` and `c`.

One can do

```
df['cumsum'] = df.groupby('keys')['values'].cumsum()

   keys  values  cumsum
0     a       1       1
1     a       5       6
2     a       6      12
3     a       8      20
4     b       2       2
5     b       4       6
6     b       7      13
7     b       7      20
8     c       1       1
9     c       1       2
10    c       1       3
11    c       1       4
12    c       5       9
```

but I don't know how to get the group info from this.

Comment: Just checking, does `df.groupby('keys')['values'].cumsum().mod(max_sum).groupby(df['keys']).diff().fillna(-1).lt(0).cumsum() ` do what you want?

Comment: @cs95: that looks exactly as the `group` column, so I guess it does; now I only have to understand this line :) Please add it as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can create two masks, and based on that create a `True` / `False` array.

- **m1**: All values which are greater then `max_sum` mark as `True` else `False`
- **m2**: Rows where the value in previous row `keys` is not the same as current row.

With `np.where` we basically have the following in Pseudo code:

> when m1 **or** m2 is True, return True, else False

Now we can translate `True` and `False` to 1 / 0 since they are booleans:

```
True + True

2
```

That's the reaon for `cumsum` in the last line.

**Code**:

```
max_sum = 10

m1 = df.groupby('keys')['values'].cumsum().gt(max_sum)  # all values which are greater than max_sum 
m2 = df['keys'].ne(df['keys'].shift())                  # all rows where keys change

df['group'] = np.where(m1 | m2, True, False).cumsum()


   keys  values  group
0     a       1      1
1     a       5      1
2     a       6      2
3     a       8      3
4     b       2      4
5     b       4      4
6     b       7      5
7     b       7      6
8     c       1      7
9     c       1      7
10    c       1      7
11    c       1      7
12    c       5      7
```

Comment: Interesting, I like this answer.

Comment: I think you are missing the creation of "cumsum" but I have an idea how you created that.

Comment: Very nice idea! i have to go through it to fully understand, so I upvote for now and then accept later on depending on the other answers.

Comment: Thank you @cs95 returned the upvote. And yes you are right, edited accordingly.

Comment: You can avoid the intermediate column with `m1 = df.groupby('keys')['values'].cumsum().gt(max_sum)` I think this should be equivalent.

Comment: Now that I finally understand the logic, I can say that it is a great answer, thanks a lot for it! I am going to accept the one by @cs95 as he was slightly faster (in the comments).

Comment: No worries at all, glad we could help out and share knowledge. He deserves the points more than me! So does wenben! happy coding @Cleb

Comment: Very elegant solution! Other solutions are basically iterating through the DF which you can do anything with iteration. The goal is to stay loyal to the vectorized nature of pandas.

Comment: Underlying assumption is that the keys are sorted

Comment: This answer forms different groups even when the max is not exceeded per group (2nd condtion of the problem).  It splits every row for a group after the cumsum is > max_sum first exceeded.  This is evident if you change all the keys to 'a', we place every row into a different group although the total sum for the group is not exceeded.

Answer (score 7):

We want to partition rows based on their cumulative sum, so we use `cumsum`, take the modulus with respect to `max_sum`, then find the difference to find points where the difference is negative (to mark the next group). We also need to do this per key, so the entire operation described above is done inside a `GroupBy.apply` call.

```
(df.groupby('keys')['values']
   .apply(lambda x: x.cumsum().mod(max_sum).diff())
   .fillna(-1)
   .lt(0)
   .cumsum())                 

0     1
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     4
6     5
7     6
8     7
9     7
10    7
11    7
12    7
Name: values, dtype: int64
```

---

In a comment below, I wrote:

> @Cleb Looks like my answer here is wrong. For 4, 4, 9, 2, the output
>   should be 1, 1, 2, 3 but my code will assign 1, 1, 2, 2 because cumsum
>   discounts the values.

So, here's my solution to address this corner case. Define a function that assigns groups:

```
grp = {'grp': 0}  # better than `global`, at least
def func(V):
    cumsum = 0
    grp['grp'] += 1
    grps = []
    for v in V.tolist():
        cumsum += v
        if cumsum > max_sum:
            cumsum = v
            grp['grp'] += 1
        grps.append(grp['grp'])

    return pd.Series(grps)
```

Now, call `apply`:

```
df.groupby('keys')['values'].apply(func).values
# array([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7])
```

Comment: Thanks! I have to go through it to fully understand, so I upvote for now and then accept later on depending on the other answers.

Comment: I think we over kill the problem :-) haha factorize

Comment: @Cleb Looks like my answer here is wrong. For `4, 4, 9, 2`, the output should be `1, 1, 2, 3` but my code will assign `1, 1, 2, 2` because cumsum discounts the values. Take a look and let me know if that makes sense...

Comment: Ok, I check and unselect for now to not mislead others... ;) seems the one by @erfan actually works; it returns the desired `1, 1, 2, 3`. Thanks a lot for noticing this.

Answer (score 2):

My logic , first get the `cumsum` within each group , then we need get the pervious group's max last group number `cumsum` assign to next group

```
s=(df.groupby('keys')['values'].cumsum()//10+1)
s+s.groupby(df['keys']).last().shift().fillna(0).cumsum().reindex(df['keys']).values

Out[24]: 
0     1.0
1     1.0
2     2.0
3     3.0
4     4.0
5     4.0
6     5.0
7     6.0
8     7.0
9     7.0
10    7.0
11    7.0
12    7.0
Name: values, dtype: float64
```

---

Another way

```
pd.factorize(list(zip(df['keys'],df.groupby('keys')['values'].cumsum()//10)))[0]+1
Out[51]: array([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], dtype=int64)
```

---

Method 3 Data From Pir

```
s=df.groupby('keys')['values'].rolling(2,min_periods=1).sum().gt(10)
s.loc[s.groupby(level=0).head(1).index[1:]]=True
s.cumsum()+1
Out[79]: 
keys    
a     0      1
      1      1
      2      2
      3      3
b     4      4
      5      4
      6      5
      7      6
c     8      7
      9      7
      10     7
      11     7
      12     7
d     13     8
      14     8
      15     9
      16    10
Name: values, dtype: int32
```

Comment: great knowledge of the pandas methods! +1

Comment: @Erfan adding another method :-)

Comment: wow, the second one looks like cheating :) Thanks for adding this, too!

Comment: Man the last method is crazy, gonna have to go through it step by step. btw saw your answer coming by on [twitter](https://twitter.com/PythonStack/status/1135057422157062145) :) @WeNYoBen

Answer (score 2):

#### This is not a vectorizable problem

At least not as far as I can tell

#### Setup

Consider the expanded example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'keys': [*'aaaabbbbcccccdddddddd'],
    'values': [*map(int, '156824771111544922252')]
})
```

#### Using a generator

```
def gen_groups(tups, max_sum=10):
    label = 0
    sums = {}
    for key, val in tups:
        if key not in sums:
            label += 1
            sums[key] = 0
        sums[key] += val
        if sums[key] > max_sum:
            # This resets the summation
            # to the first thing that exceeded the max
            sums[key] = val
            label += 1
        yield label

df.assign(group=[*gen_groups(zip(df['keys'], df['values']))])
```

OUTPUT

```
   keys  values  group
0     a       1      1
1     a       5      1
2     a       6      2
3     a       8      3
4     b       2      4
5     b       4      4
6     b       7      5
7     b       7      6
8     c       1      7
9     c       1      7
10    c       1      7
11    c       1      7
12    c       5      7
13    d       4      8  # First group for `key == d` 
14    d       4      8  # Still same group because `4 + 4 <= 10`
15    d       9      9  # New group because `4 + 4 + 9 > 10`
16    d       2     10  # New group because `9 + 2 > 10`
17    d       2     10  # Same group because `2 + 2 < = 10`
18    d       2     10  # Same group because `2 + 2 + 2 <= 10`
19    d       5     11  # New Group because `2 + 2 + 2 + 5 > 10`
20    d       2     11  # Same Group because `5 + 2 <= 10`
```

Comment: Are you sure? Just checked with my method, gave correct result.

Comment: Will check it now

Comment: Can confirm that @Erfan's answer gives the correct results. yours works fine, too, thanks.

Comment: @Erfan I show you get the same result but something keeps nagging at my brain.  I'll sort it out shortly

Comment: Right!!  If I extend the groups out further, you only capture the first time the cumsum exceeds the `max_sum` and continue to assign a new group number for each row.

Comment: Then I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but I thought that was the purpose. Once the threshold is exceeded it keeps being exceeded until a new group is reached. Could you maybe jump in and explain what is the correct output here? @Cleb. For example look at `index 3` in expected output of OP.

Comment: @Erfan: oops, that's quite embarrassing: the output in this answer is actually what I was after, however, the way I phrased the question, yours is actually correct; I did not choose the best minimal example apparently. I go to sleep now and then decide tomorrow how to solve this dilemma :)

Comment: @Cleb I'm fine with whatever you choose.  Just remember: When life gives you dilemma's, make dilemmonaid. /mike_drop

Comment: I probably go with @Erfan's answer as he answered the question based on the (apparently) poor example I chose. But interesting to see that you better understand want I want than I did :) Thanks once more!

Answer (score 0):

I create groupID per `cumsum` and use it to group again together with `keys` to derive the `ngroup` per `keys-cumsum`

```
max_sum = 10
s = df.groupby('keys').values.cumsum().gt(max_sum ).cumsum()
df.groupby([df['keys'], s]).ngroup() + 1

Out[461]:
0     1
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     4
6     5
7     6
8     7
9     7
10    7
11    7
12    7
dtype: int64
```